# Amplitude of a wave

Tags: waves, definition, conventions

The wave equation
$$y= A \sin^2(kx-\omega t)$$
should have an amplitude $A$. But in textbook, it is given that amplitude is $A/2$. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Comment: Concepts of Physics part 1. Page 322

Comment: As a general rule please give the author name(s) to physics books as they tend to have very similar (even identical titles) - e.g. "Introduction to ...".  No one said physicists were imagnitative. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sine squared function ranges between $0$ and $1$.

The given function ranges between $y=0$ and $y=A$ and is symmetrical about $y=A/2$.  So you can think of it as an oscillating function of amplitude $A/2$ with an offset of $A/2$.

Answer (score 7):

Note that by using the simple trigonometric identity $$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x$$ then

$$\rightarrow \sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$

Therefore we can write the equation
$$y= A \sin^2(kx-mt)\tag1$$ as

$$y= \frac{A}{2}[1−\cos(2kx−2mt)]$$  which means that equation (1) actually represents a wave with amplitude $\frac{A}{2}$.